# Are these lines of scala code equivalent?

Tags: scala

Given an object myObject which has a method getSomething which takes in a String parameter and returns a String

Are #1 and #2 equivalent?

1. `val foo = myOjbect.getSomething("foo")`
2. `val foo = myOjbect getSomething "foo"`

And are either acceptable / preferred over the other? When would you use 1 vs 2 and vica versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are strictly equivalent.

Regarding your second question, Stack Overflow is not really meant to decide what is acceptable or preferred. Yet you can refer to the [scala documentation on method invocation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html) that states this:

> Scala has a special punctuation-free syntax for invoking methods that take one argument. Many Scala programmers use this notation for symbolic-named methods:
>
> ```
> // recommended
> a + b
>
> // legal, but less readable
> a+b
>
> // legal, but definitely strange
> a.+(b)
> ```
>
> but avoid it for almost all alphabetic-named methods:
>
> ```
> // recommended
> names.mkString(",")
>
> // also sometimes seen; controversial
> names mkString ","
> ```

Comment: the documentation linked to, and the examples provided, do certainly help clear it up for me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes they are identical.
2. There is no consensus (I don't think it is possible to achieve one) which form are preferable (such questions are offtopic here).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are identical.
I mostly use the 2nd version when developing tests like:

```
result mustEqual "Hello"
```